# get wifi mac address of my device?

Tags: java, android

I want to access the wifi mac address of my device and post that to a server , I used below method :

```
 public void accessAdress(){
    //Detect Bluetooth Address
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String address = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

But it gave me something like this : 02:00:00:00:00:00 .
What should i do to access my real wifi mac adress ?
(The android version of my device is : 7.0)

Answer (score 0):

The mac address is obfuscated as of Android 6.0

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.
>
> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id).

People have used this [work around](http://robinhenniges.com/en/android6-get-mac-address-programmatically):

```
public static String getMacAddr() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me , do you know how to get Bluetooth address instead of wifi mac address ?